# Отформатировать номер телефона под шаблон c#

Tags: c#

`String tel_str = "0982468089";`

Как из номера телефона 0982468089 сделать (098) 246-80-89

Возможно через Regex.Replace это делается, но не нахожу как

Comment: [первые 2-3 ссылки уже содержат ответ](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4+%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD+c%23)

Answer (score 2):

Давайте заморочимся и сделаем универсальную функцию, создающую форматтеры по задаваемому шаблону.

```
public static Func<string, string> CreateFormatter(string input, string pattern)
{
    var charMap = new Dictionary<int, char>();

    for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!input.Contains(pattern[i]))
        {
            charMap.Add(i, pattern[i]);
        }
    }

    Func<string, string> formatter = s =>
    {
        foreach (var kvp in charMap)
        {
            s = s.Insert(kvp.Key, kvp.Value.ToString());
        }
        return s;
    };

    return formatter;
}
```

Номер телефона, который вы представили, состоит из десяти символов. Поэтому на входе нашей функции - строка из десяти символов. Это необязательно цифры, могут быть любые символы.

Вторым параметром идёт шаблон. В нём присутствуют те же самые десять символов и любые другие символы, которые нужно добавить: скобки, пробел, тире и т. п.

Использование:

```
var formatter = CreateFormatter("1234567890", "(123) 456-78-90");
//var formatter = CreateFormatter("abcdefghij", "(abc) def-gh-ij");

string phone = "0982468089";
string result = formatter(phone);

Console.WriteLine(phone);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```