# Как подставлять строку с номеров в паттерн Regex?

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Не могу понять, как подставлять в паттерн @"+7 (\d\d\d) \d\d\d \d\d-\d\d" номер телефона 9883334422? Как правильно использовать Regex, чтобы это реализовать?

Comment: Что имеете ввиду под "подставлять в паттерн"? Хотите проверить номер телефона на соответствие шаблону или что?

Comment: @АндрейNOP Как проверить, я знаю, вот не могу понять, как с помощью Regex из строки "9996664422" получить строку "+7 (999) 666 44-22", то есть я хочу сделать маску для строки

Comment: Regex используется для _парсинга_, а вам нужно _форматирование_. | Зацените https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1185403/184217

Answer (score 4):

Например, с помощью замены:

```
var s1 = "9883334422";
var s2 = Regex.Replace(s1, @"(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d\d)(\d\d)", "+7 ($1) $2 $3-$4");
Console.WriteLine(s2); // +7 (988) 333 44-22
```

Здесь $N используется для вставки N-й захваченной группы из входной строки

Answer (score 2):

Т.к. правильный ответ уже дан, пофантазирую немного.
*код сгенерирован автоматически на сайте regex101.com:*

```c#
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"^(?:\+?7|8)?[ (-]*(\d{3})[ )-]*(\d{3})[ -]*(\d{2})[ -]*(\d{2})";
        string substitution = "+7 ($1) $2 $3-$4";
        string input = @"918 177 77 47
89181777747
9181777747
8 918 177-77-47
+7(918)177 77 47
+79181777747
8(918)1777747
8-918-177-77-47
8(918)177-77-47
";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
//result<<
/*
+7 (918) 177 77-47
+7 (918) 177 77-47
+7 (918) 177 77-47
+7 (918) 177 77-47
+7 (918) 177 77-47
+7 (918) 177 77-47
+7 (918) 177 77-47
+7 (918) 177 77-47
+7 (918) 177 77-47
*/
```

О регулярном выражении

```regex
^(?:\+?7|8)?[ (-]*(\d{3})[ )-]*(\d{3})[ -]*(\d{2})[ -]*(\d{2})"
```

`^(?:\+?7|8)?` - начало строки с необязательной незахватываемой группой в которой получаем +7 или 8
`[ (-]*` - ноль и более символов пробела тире и открывающихся скобок
`(\d{3})` - три цифры захватываемые в первую группу, это код оператора
`[ )-]*` - ноль и более символов пробела тире и закрывающихся скобок
`(\d{3})` - вторая группа, первые 3 цифры номера
`[ -]*` - ноль и более символов пробела и тире
`(\d{2})` - треть группа, 4 и 5 символ номера
`[ -]*` - ноль и более символов пробела и тире
`(\d{2})` - четвертая группа, 6 и 7 символ номера

Далее эти группы подставляем в необходимый шаблон, где $цифра соответствует номер захваченной группы:

```
string substitution = "+7 ($1) $2 $3-$4";
```