# Валидатор телефонного номера на php (регулярное выражение)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно написать регулярное выражение для номера телефона в таком формате

```
+d(ddd)ddd-dd-dd
```

Пробовал так:

```
#^(\+\d)[\- ]?)?(\(?\d{3}\)?[\- ]?)?[\d\- ]{7,10}$#
```

Не работает.

Comment: у вас явно регулярка не для примера выше

Comment: Не силен в регулярках, можешь подсказать какая подойдет в моем случае?

Comment: `\+\d\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}`

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1430790/485997 - посмотрите ответы тут, возможно пригодится

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```php
<?php

$re = '#^\+\d\(\d{3}\)\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}$#';
if (preg_match($re, "+7(101)567-34-12")) {
    echo "Valid!";
}
```

**Подробности**

- `^` - начало строки
- `\+` - символ `+`
- `\d` - одна цифра
- `\(` - символ `(`
- `\d{3}` - три цифры
- `\)` - символ `)`
- `\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}` - три цифры, `-`, две цифры, `-` и две цифры
- `$` - конец строки.

См. [пример использования](https://regex101.com/r/55kj0q/1).